# PHP/MySQL multiple queries ok?

Tags: php, mysql

My question is regarding performance and script optimization. I'm fairly new to PHP and I have something like the following:

```
$Connection = new mysqli($Server, $DBUsername, $DBPassword, $DBName);
$Connection->query("UPDATE Basket SET Apples='$Apples', Oranges='$Oranges', Bananas='$Bananas' WHERE BasketName='$BasketName'"); 
$Connection->query("UPDATE Bag SET Napkins='$Napkins' WHERE BagName='$BagName'");
$Connection->query("UPDATE Drinks SET Water='$Water' WHERE DrinksName='$DrinksName'");
```

Is it ok that I have multiple $Connection->query, one for each table or is there a better way that's faster to write this?

Comment: you can use a multi-query and while you're at it, use a prepared statement. You're open to an sql injection.

Comment: would you be so kind to show me an example of what you mean?

Comment: I'm getting my variables from the URL and I use the following to protect against sql injections: $BasketName = mysqli_real_escape_string($Connection, $_GET['BasketName']); Is that not enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your code is vulnerable to a [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). You should switch to prepared statements asap.

Using mysqli_real_escape_string is not enough to prevent SQL injections. See [Is “mysqli_real_escape_string” enough to avoid SQL injection or other SQL attacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391315/is-mysqli-real-escape-string-enough-to-avoid-sql-injection-or-other-sql-attack)

An [example](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) of a prepared statement:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $lastname, $email);

// set parameters and execute
$firstname = "John";
$lastname = "Doe";
$email = "john@example.com";
$stmt->execute();
```

To answer your original question. You could use [mysqli::multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php). I personally find it a lot cleaner if the queries are split up query per query.

Comment: np :) will remove prev comment